# Access SQL: How select the smallest difference between two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a Problem with my SQL-code. I hope you can help me... :)

Condition is:

->Show me the latest Price of a Product!

Because the Price of a product could Change after a certain time.
So my idea of the query is,

select the productname, from product where the difference between  currentdate and dateofmodification is the smallest.

But I dont know how can i formulate this correctly in SQL code? Could someone help me?

Thank you

Kind regards!

Comment: you can select date diff between currentdate and dateofmodification and order by that asc and take first row

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table(s) structure(s), some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: share table structure and sample

Comment: table Name is DAILYVALUES, that Shows the daily purchases and sales of products, that means that a product can be listed many times and I need the latest values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `datediff()` at all.  Assuming all values of `dateofmodification` are in the past:

```
select top 1 productname
from product 
order by dateofmodification desc;
```

For a modification date, this seems like a very reasonable assumption.

Note:  By not using a function on the column, the SQL engine can use an index, greatly speeding up the query.

Comment: Yep. No need to overcomplicate matters.